# Can I preserve nested schema in cosmosdb to spark connector?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb

I have just started the azure cosmosdb to spark connector to bring in my cosmosdb collection into a spark dataframe.  Unfortunately, with a basic **select * from coll** query, it flattens any nested structure into a string.  The format of this string isnt even json, so I dont know how to parse it, the format looks like:

```
{key1=value,key2=anothervalue}
```

Is there a way the cosmosdb connector can preserve the nested structure in spark, OR is there a way I can parse this string format in spark?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the Spark connector are you using, Zach?

The connector derives the schema by sampling a subset of the data. If there is no good type for a property then it will use String. You can try to increase the sampling size with schema_samplesize config, the default value is 1000. Is there a chance that you have multiple types for the property value? or is it StructType and Null? For the latter case, I think it will be fixed in version 0.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but had the same problem in 2020, so:

- using `ToString(json_col)` in the query to CosmosDb will give you a column of type string with `VALID` json in it (`:` and `"` instead of `=` and nothing).
- if the schema of all documents you query is the same, you can also set it manually in the normal spark way (`spark.read....schema(your_schema)...`).